# VWO data not pushed into custom dimension in GA

Tags: google-analytics, vwo

I have followed everything detailed in this [VWO reference doc](https://vwo.com/knowledge/vwo-integration-with-ua/). After waiting a day, still nothing shows up in my GA custom dimensions report.

Debugging the page, nothing is showing up in the DOM as related to the custom dimension from VWO. According to the reference doc, "VarName" and "CampID" should both show up as parameters in the DOM.

I am using the synchronous snippet in VWO inserted before `</head>` and also before the GA snippet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share the site URL where it is happening?